# How to encode a feature which has a list of categorical values in each row for training an machine learning model?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset where I have list of categorical values as value of a feature. How can I encode it to train a model?

For example, I have some data like:

```
feature1: [a, b, c]
feature2: [[category1, category2, category3], [category2], [category3, category4]]
```

how to encode feature2?

Comment: Use one-hot encoding, make each list into a vector with the size being the total number of categories, ones on the selected categories and zeros elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
    
y = [
        ('Raj', 'Penny'),
        ('Amy', 'Raj'),
        ('Sheldon', 'Penny'),
        ('Leonard', 'Amy'),
        ('Amy', 'Leonard')
    ]
    
one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer()

print(one_hot.fit_transform(y))

print(one_hot.classes_)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LabelEncoder` AND `OneHotEncode` :-

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x=LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0]=labelencoder_x.fit_transform(X[:,0])   
onehotencoder_x=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0]) 
X=onehotencoder_x.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

I think from this you can get the idea.